# How to install pg_cron on Big Sur Apple M1?

Tags: postgresql, cron, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, pg-cron

- I am trying to install pg_cron on my local machine Big Sur M1 for development https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron
- I cannot find any instructions on how to install this on M1
- sudo yum install -y pg_cron_12 does not work
- sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12-cron doesnt work either
- My PostgreSQL version is 13.4, how do I install pg_cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to install from source. The documentation describes that:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron.git
cd pg_cron
# Ensure pg_config is in your path, e.g.
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-12/bin:$PATH
make && sudo PATH=$PATH make install
```

You will need GNU make, a C compiler and the PostgreSQL headers installed; other dependencies have to be found out the hard way, as the documentation is silent about them.